# How to extract the clicked value in the drop down menu using React Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Im using Material UI React, and building a dropdown with several options inside it. My question is, if I select two options from two dropdowns from the menu, how to intercept or record what option was clicked?

My code looks like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
    import Popover, { PopoverAnimationVertical } from 'material-
    ui/Popover';
    import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
    import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
    import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-
    drop-right';
    import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';

export default class PopoverExampleAnimation extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  open: false,
 };
}

handleTouchTap = (event) => {
// This prevents ghost click.
event.preventDefault();

this.setState({
  open: true,
  anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
 });
};

handleRequestClose = () => {
this.setState({
  open: false,
});
};

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <RaisedButton
        onClick={this.handleTouchTap}
        label="FILTER"
        labelColor="#26A69A"
    />
    <Popover
        open={this.state.open}
        anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom' }}
        targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top' }}
        onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        animation={PopoverAnimationVertical}
    >
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem
            primaryText="NAME"
            rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
            menuItems={[
              <MenuItem primaryText="OPTION 1" />,
              <Divider />,
              <MenuItem primaryText="OPTION 2" />,
            ]}
        />

        <Divider />
        <MenuItem
            primaryText="ID"
            rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
            menuItemStyle={{ backgroundcolor: '#E0F2F1' }}
            menuItems={[
              <MenuItem primaryText="1" />,
              <Divider />,
              <MenuItem primaryText="2" />,
              <Divider />,
              <MenuItem primaryText="3" />,
              <Divider />,
              <MenuItem primaryText="4" />,
            ]}
        />
        <Divider />
        <RaisedButton
            label="APPLY"
            style={{ margin: 2, width: '60px' }}
            labelColor="#FAFAFA"
            backgroundColor="#26A69A"
        />
        <RaisedButton
            label="CANCEL"
            style={{ margin: 22, width: '60px' }}
            labelColor="#26A69A"
        />

      </Menu>
    </Popover>
  </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Im using this component as a way to get parameters and then filter a table based on the options selected under the dropdown menu.

EDIT: I added the image of how it looks for clarification.
[image]

Comment: `dropdown`, where is it ? I think i met a ghost !!

Comment: I use a popover over a button to display two more menu items which have options nested inside them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing the clicked options in the state. You could add a `clicked` array that keeps track. Then add `onClick` methods in the various options that will call a function that pushes to `this.state.clicked`. Remember to bind this callback in the constructor (it looks like you did not bind the other callbacks, such as `handleRequestClose`...is this not causing you problems?).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.setState({
    open: true,
    anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    clicked: [],
  });

  this.optionClicked = this.optionClicked.bind(this);
};

function optionClicked(whichOption) {
  this.state.clicked.push(whichOption);
}

...

<MenuItem
  primaryText="NAME"
  rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
  menuItems={[
    <MenuItem primaryText="OPTION 1" onClick={() => this.optionClicked('OPTION 1')}/>,
    <Divider />,
    <MenuItem primaryText="OPTION 2"  onClick={() => this.optionClicked('OPTION 2')}/>,
  ]}
/>
```

You can then access the array from `this.state.clicked` and do with it as you wish.